# Python: How to write to and read from an existing PseudoTerminal (pty/pts)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pty

I am attempting to programmatically interact with an existing program that provides an interface via a pseudo terminal (/dev/pts/1)

I have a poor understanding of how this works.  I can currently interact crudely but successfully with:
`echo SomeCommandToSend >> /dev/pts/1`

And can equally crudely retrieve results with:
`cat /dev/pts/1`

Question: How can I cleanly and programmatically interact with this pseudo terminal from Python?

I have looked at [these docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html) but was unable to see how to use that in this case, as I do not want to spawn a new process, just communicate with an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will once print `hello` to your terminal (execute `tty` in your terminal to get `/dev/pts/n`) and infinitly read from terminal.

```
import sys                                           

with open("/dev/pts/1", "wb+", buffering=0) as term:
    term.write("hello".encode())
    while True:
        print(term.read(1).decode(), end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: thanks! Do you have a recommendation how to replicate that print syntax in python 2?

Comment: @MtlDev, Yes, replace `print` to `sys.stdout.write`